# Testing Kafka Processor API that uses SpecificAvroSerde

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-schema-registry

I'm trying to write unit test for a custom stream processor and got stuck with serializing the message i need to send for the test. I followed this example by kafka: https://kafka.apache.org/11/documentation/streams/developer-guide/testing.html . I use SpecificAvroSerde for a custom class (auto genereted avro class) in my stream, but i cant configure it in the test with the MockSchemaRegistryClient(), I only can point to the URL of SR.

```
    Serde<MyCustomObject> valueSerde = new SpecificAvroSerde<>();
    Map<String, String> valueSerdeConfig = new HashMap<>();
    valueSerdeConfig.put(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, "fake");
    valueSerdeConfig.put(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.AUTO_REGISTER_SCHEMAS, "true");
    valueSerde.configure(valueSerdeConfig, false);
    ConsumerRecordFactory<Long, MyCustomObject> recordFactory = new ConsumerRecordFactory<>(new LongSerializer(), valueSerde.serializer());
```

With KafkaAvroSerializer i can initialize it like this:

```
KafkaAvroSerializer serializer = new KafkaAvroSerializer(schemaRegistryClient);
```

but ConsumerRecordFactory won't take KafkaAvroSerializer as an argument.

Is there any alternative to this or a way that I'm not aware of for doing this?

I'll appreciate any help, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the proposed solution, but I did managed to find one today. Serdes consists of a serializer and deserializer: https://kafka.apache.org/11/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/Serdes.html#serdeFrom-org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer-org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer- so I constructed my Serde from KafkaAvroSerializer and KafkaAvroDeserializer like this:

```
Serde serde = Serdes.serdeFrom(new KafkaAvroSerializer(client), new KafkaAvroDeserializer(client));
```

Every class that implements Serializer< T > can be part of a Serde.

Answer (score 0):

I'm generating Java models for all Avro definitions:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ ! -f avro-tools-1.8.2.jar ]; then
    wget http://tux.rainside.sk/apache/avro/avro-1.8.2/java/avro-tools-1.8.2.jar
    chmod +x avro-tools-1.8.2.jar
fi

java -jar avro-tools-1.8.2.jar compile schema ../avro/raw/* ../../java/
```

Then I just generate few messages into mocked Kafka cluster

```
public abstract class ViewPageEventGenerator {

    @NotNull
    public static KeyValue<List, HashMap<String, String>> getSimpleViewPages() {
        List<KeyValue<CustomerKey, ViewPage>> inputValues = new ArrayList<>();
        HashMap<String, String> requestExpectedValuePairs = new HashMap<>();

        inputValues = Arrays.asList(
                new KeyValue<>(
                        new CustomerKey(1912, "Alan Turing"),
                        new ViewPage("Alan Turing", false,
                                Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())),
                                "https://alan.turing/", "192.168.0.1", "Turing Machine", "Punch card"
                        )
                ),
                new KeyValue<>(
                        new CustomerKey(1912, "Alan Turing"),
                        new ViewPage("Alan Turing", false,
                                Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() + 100)),
                                "https://alan.turing/", "192.168.0.1", "Turing Machine", "Punch card"
                        )
                ),
                new KeyValue<>(
                        new CustomerKey(1912, "Alan Turing"),
                        new ViewPage("Alan Turing", false,
                                Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() + 200)),
                                "https://alan.turing/", "192.168.0.1", "Turing Machine", "Punch card"
                        )
                )
        );
        requestExpectedValuePairs.put(
                "{project_id: 1912}",
                "{\"success\":true,\"data\":{\"count\":3}}"
        );

        return new KeyValue<>(inputValues, requestExpectedValuePairs);
    }
}
```

And that's it. In topology I work with generated Java models (classes) based on Avro definitions.